# Can capital ships be moved through Thera?

Tags: eve-online

I need to move a rorqual and a thanatos but I don't want to take cyno's from the far south to the north.

If I have fortuitous connections - could I move them via Thera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. you can't. Maximum mass per jump on Thera whormholes has been specifically set by CCP so that no capital ships or supers can enter Thera, which makes it a capital-free system, just like High-Sec.

The only exception, because of mass, are non-combat capital ships, which are Freighters (including Bowhead) & Jump Freighters. (Also, Orca, which is sometimes considered as a cap by a few peoples).

Comment: I double checked this with a player in Volta and he gave me the same answer.